# Wifi Connected but internet not working

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

The wifi is connected to my Mac but the internet isn't working. On my phone, it is perfectly fine.

I have tried:

1. using a personal hotspot from my phone to my computer but the internet still doesn't work.
2. in recovery mode, the internet works.
3. Restarting Router (although I don't think the problem is there)

Any help would be much appreciated as I have a lot of work due :0 
Thank you in advance!!!

Edit (links to wifi tab):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of all the tabs for your wifi connection under System Preferences?

Comment: Ok hmmm once again the internet stopped working. Sba I call Apple help desk

Comment: It's Wi-Fi, TCP/IP, DNS, WINS, 802.1x, Proxies, Hardware

Comment: I don't need a list of them - I want to see a screenshot of each of their contents. Post them as an edit to the original question.

Comment: The issue is I'm currently on my phone and no access to a computer so I can't insert photos :/

Comment: Ok - it will be impossible to make a more educated answer than I posted below until we can see the settings. apple is basically going to do the same if you call or take it in

Comment: Hmm give me a few I'll try. I said the image is too big when I tried to use it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RlsZW
https://imgur.com/a/3XBp6
https://imgur.com/a/NBwHb
https://imgur.com/a/PyUDl

Comment: Hey, could only post two links on the main page so test is above ^

Comment: See that DNS server - 192.168.0.1? Click it and click the minus sign at the bottom. You'll see it turn from black to grey. That will fix your problem

Comment: Hey, I am unable to do that. I can only press the minus button. I can't even click on the DNS server 192.168.0.1

Comment: When you say "internet is not working" - when you go into a browser and you see the status bar at the bottom when you try to load a website, which step is it hung up on? Connecting, Resolving host, etc.?

Comment: On the browser it just keeps on loading while other applications don't work as well. Even if I use personal hotspot (4g) and connect, the internet doesn't work.

Comment: It says DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Comment: Also not sure if it helps, when I connect my phone, it charges but in settings it says iPhone USB not connected

Answer (score 1):

Typical advice I give in this situation is to check your TCP/IP Settings under the wifi connection in your Network controls in System Preferences. Make sure you're using DHCP and no DNS servers are hard coded. Also make sure you don't have some kind of proxy software or VPN running on your computer.

Edit: try connecting your phone via USB and choosing that connection when you turn on hotspot and see if it works

Edit2: original poster posted a screenshot showing a hard coded DNS server. I recommend clicking on all hard coded DNS servers, clicking minus, and removing them.

edit3: the other issue may not be the wifi, but the modem to your internet provider.

Comment: There is no VPN on ATM and under my Configure IPv4, I'm using DHCP. There is no DNS hard coded severs I believe

Comment: It works when my phone is connected via USB

Comment: Definitely a config issue with your wifi network connection in settings.

Comment: I have tried all way but nothing has resolved it. It works fine in recovery mode but any time else nothing. Any thing else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Open network preferences.
2. Select your WiFi card on the left.
3. Click "Advanced"
4. Click "Proxies" tab.
   5.Enable "Automatic Proxy Configuration"
5. Close Network Preferences
6. Quit Safari.
7. Reboot your Mac and try again.